# Lubuntu won't start anymore after completely removing ubuntu-desktop

Tags: lubuntu, data-recovery

I installed `ubuntu-desktop`, `kubuntu-desktop` and `xubuntu-desktop` on my Lubuntu.

I wanted to remove them and found [this](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntucat/pure-lubuntu-13-04/). I first used the command to remove `ubuntu-desktop`. While running it, I noticed that it was also deleting KDE packages.

The command took a while and I had to go away, so I locked the screen (And it used the lock screen from `ubuntu-desktop`). After 2 hours I came back and pressed a button to wake from standby. After that it reacted to NOTHING so I had to do a forced shutdown.

And now it won't start anymore (black screen). I can still get into Windows and safemode. I tried safemode, enabling network and running `apt-get install lubuntu-desktop`,  but it looks like it already is there. I tried `dpkg` and `apt-get autoremove` and doing `apt-get install lubuntu-desktop` again, but it still looks like it already is there. When I reboot now I do get the Lubuntu logo but after that, black screen again.

I also tried removing `lubuntu-desktop` and installing it again but that didn't help either.

What should I do? (except reinstalling)

Comment: Did you try to reinstall LXDM?

Comment: No. Will that work?

Comment: I don't know. It doesn't hurt trying.

Comment: Because you force shut it down make sure that there aren't any package errors. Try running this: `sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt-get install -f && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: @RaboRoss Hm, will try. Will I not lose my documents?

Comment: @RaboRoss Tried it and it didn't work. :(

Comment: @ToDo Tried it, LXDM isn't an existing package.

Comment: try to remove all desktops and then installing lubuntu again? it might work (just an idea from me).

Comment: On my Ubuntu 13.04, `sudo apt-get install lxdm' works. Try installing lightDM instead.

Comment: Oh, I already reinstalled now. Forgot to post that