# Can I run Ubuntu on my old laptop?

Tags: 13.04

I want to install my first Linux ever, and I have already given up on Mint because it requires PAE, which I believe my processor doesn't support. It's an old IBM ThinkPad:

- 1GB of RAM
- Pentium M 1.7GHz
- Graphics card: ATI Mobility Radeon 9600 Series

So, can I run Ubuntu normally? Or Kubuntu, or even Xubuntu? If I chose one of these two, would there be some downsides in comparison to Ubuntu?

I'm talking about the latest versions of these distros, 13.04 I guess.

Comment: I recommend that you go with [Lubuntu](http://www.lubuntu.net/)

Comment: I would just try it on a live use, and if the graphics aren't that bad install it. I would also recommend LUbuntu if unity is too slow.

Comment: Mitch, what about Xubuntu?

Comment: I would go for Xubuntu, or if possible, the latest Ubuntu plus the XFCE Desktop Environment, which will make your system more stable than Lubuntu. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to run Ubuntu with Unity, could work with your graphic card. If the systems runs too slow, you change the Desktop after install and try Xubuntu for example by installing it with

`sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop`

or try Lubuntu

`sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop`

the software you can use is the same on all systems, only the desktop has less effects Xubuntu less than Ubuntu and Lubuntu less than Xubuntu

Comment: NEVER recommend installing the desktop packages. NEVER. Would have voted down if I had enough reputation.

Comment: I wonder why? It will work safe. Can you please say why? @com.BOY? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wonder too. Doing apt-get autoremove will clean up a lot and other packages you do not need, can be purged by hand.

Comment: @GeppettvsD'Constanzo It will litter your applications menu with almost-the-same apps. And if you want to remove it, you will need to delete the unneeded applications by hand.

Comment: I can't yet see a major issue with that @com.BOY, with that arguments can you -please- explain why you used uppercase when saying "NEVER" and why would you down vote a good answer? Sorry but I don't get your point. Thank you.

Comment: @GeppettvsD'Constanzo Sorry I exaggerated, but my point was it loads your applications menu with crap and [removing it again can be a nightmare, it's easy to make a mistake](http://askubuntu.com/questions/306486/lubuntu-wont-start-anymore-after-completely-removing-ubuntu-desktop). Since that I recommend against doing it. But you are right, I exaggerated. Sorry.